# Dynamic notifications

Tags: support, notifications, live-refresh

Why don't notifications dynamically pop up as soon as they occur like on Facebook?

I need to refresh page in order to see the notifications.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why don't notifications dynamically pop up as soon as they occur like on Facebook?

Because that's annoying and distracting. This is not Facebook, so we try to keep those things to a minimum whenever possible.

> I need to refresh page in order to see the notifications.

No, you don't. All you have to do is click on the notification banner (the gray box that pops up). That will cause the new content to load in place immediately.

In this way, we get the benefits of automatic updates, without the annoyance and distraction. 
Will someone please tell Facebook how it's done?